# LibGDX Database Leak

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I keep getting this error when I run my application in LibGDX:

> Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly
>   and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

How would I fix it?

Comment: Steps to produce this error ?

Comment: It doesnt crash the app

Comment: What do you mean by "steps to produce this error"? I don't know what is causing it

Comment: Could you post relevant parts of your code?